# Another declined flag that I don't understand

Tags: discussion, flagging

Sorry again, but this time the declined flag was about [this answer](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/a/4917/3260) that was deleted for an unknown reason.

So I flagged it by calling a moderator (there wasn't another flag that would fit better) and explaining that the deleted answer was correct, so it should be undeleted.

However, the flag was declined for the reason: "flags should only be used to make moderators aware of content that requires their intervention". That's exactly what I did: I wanted to make a moderator aware of this correct content that needed a intervention (undelete).

Anyway, the answer was actually undeleted so I do not understand why this flag was declined.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be that the answer had been undeleted by the time a Mod got to it?  Or that the answer was originally deleted by the owner?  I'm not 100% sure what happened, but those are my first two guesses.